# Trying to link from one view page to another through different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I've created a marketplace site where my users (sellers) create collections and then add listings to each collection to sell. Any shopper can now shop by all listings (Home page) or by all collections (**sections.html.erb**). Each collection on the sections view page displays the first 3 listing images along with the name of the collection.

I want to be able to click from the **sections.html.erb** page directly to the individual collection page **shopcollected.html.erb** which displays all listings in that collection.

Separately, I created a user shop page that displays all collections from that user (**shopcollections.html.erb**). From there I can successfully click on any collection name and go to the individual collections page **shopcollected.html.erb**, all good.

But when I click on the collection name (in this case it's collection_id=13) from the **sections.html.erb**, I get this error:

```
"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListingsController#shopcollected"
"Couldn't find User with 'id'=13".
```

The url shows:

```
http://localhost:3000/shopcollected/13
```

I see this is recognizing the collection_id, but it's not recognizing the user for this collection. But I thought my controller def **shopcollected** already defines the user, so shouldn't that be fine? Is the missing piece in my "link_to"? I'm confused...

Controller def **sections**:

```
@collections = Collection.includes(:listings).order(created_at: :desc)
```

View file **sections.html.erb** link:

```
<%= link_to "#{collection.name}", shopcollected_path(collection) %>
```

Controller def **shopcollections**:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@listings = Listing.where(collection: params[:collection_id])
@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
```

View file **shopcollections.html.erb** link:

```
<%= link_to "#{collection.name}", shopcollected_path(collection_id: collection) %>
```

Controller def **shopcollected**:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
@listings = Listing.where(collection: params[:collection_id])
```

ROUTES:

```
get '/pages/sections' => 'pages#sections', as: 'sections'
get '/shopcollections/:id' => 'listings#shopcollections', as: 'shopcollections'
get '/shopcollected/:id' => 'listings#shopcollected', as: 'shopcollected'
```

Comment: Could you paste from your routes file the shopcollections paths?

Comment: You say the collection_id is 13, but the URL shows 15. Also, why do you add the collection_id: in the link_to within shopcollections? I'd think you would want something like `link_to "text", @collection` since you have resourceful routes.

Comment: @fred, sorry the 15 should be 13. When I add [at]collections in link_to, the error I get is: "ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Pages#sections" and "No route matches {:action=>"shopcollected", :controller=>"listings", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"

Answer (score 0):

This is a routing problem:

In Rails 4, you can visit: http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes and see all your routes.

Your `shopcollected_path(collection)` is correctly going to your `shopcollected_path`, but the `:id` is the collection id. But in your action, you are looking for the user by :id and it breaks.

If you want the collection to be scoped by user, then you're going to have to pass in the user id somewhere in the route. I think what you want is nested routing:

**EDIT**

It looks like you always want to look up a User for the `shopcollections` and `shopcollected` actions.

**routes**

```
get '/pages/sections' => 'pages#sections', as: 'sections'
resources :users do
  get 'shopcollections/:id' => 'listings#shopcollections', as: 'shopcollection'
  get 'shopcollected/:id' => 'listings#shopcollected', as: 'shopcollected'
end
```

**listings_controller.rb**

```
def shopcollections
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @shopcollection = @user.collections.find(params[:id])
  @listings = @shopcollection.listings # I imagine this is a relationship?
end   

def shopcollected
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @shopcollection = @user.collections.find(params[:id])
  @listings = @shopcollection.listings # I imagine this is a relationship?
end
```

I'm making some assumptions about your relationships, but I think that's what you want.

Comment: But don't I need 2 routes, one for the main sections page (sections.html.erb) and the other for the user shop collections page (shopcollections.html.erb)? If I edit the shopcollections route, that won't affect my currently working user profile collections page 'shopcollections'?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean. I edited my resources :users to add "do resources :shopcollections". Then I changed my link_to. And I then do I need to change anything in controllers?

Comment: You'll have to change your controller actions so that they look up collection by `:id` `Collection.find(params[:id])` and listing by collection id `Listing.where(collection_id: params[:id])` and then User by `:user_id` `User.find(params[:user_id])`.

Comment: Sorry a little lost. I edited my routes for :users. Do I then remove my get /shopcollections/:id? And then when I edit my Controller#sections, my page now breaks with errors: "Couldn't find User with 'id'=".

Comment: Thanks Evan, I'll give it a try and will let you know.

Comment: So I changed my routes and controller file per your suggestions above and now my routes helper path says: user_user_shopcollected_path. Is that correct? Also, now my shop collections page breaks.

Comment: Including @fred - I don't understand why this is a routing error when the page I'm targeting **shopcollected.html.erb** displays just fine when I'm clicking from the user shop page **shop.html.erb**. Isn't this just about defining the user in the controller#sections to tie the collection item to the user who created it?

Comment: Oh! Of course, I forgot that nesting resources auto-prefixes. Editing.

Comment: any chance you can post your edits in a new answer so I can see clearly what's changed?

Comment: Is there someone who can help me?